# golang timing out reading from channel using range

Tags: go, timeout, channel

My code looks like this:

```
outChannel := make(chan struct{})
...
for out := range outChannel {
   ...
}
```

I have a producer writing to `outChannel` and would like to timeout on reading from it (if overall processing takes more than XX seconds). 
What would be the proper way to do so?

As I've only seen construct (at: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Timeouts) using `select` with multiple `case`s reading from the channels, however, this seems not applicable once using `range`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do something similar, but use single timeout channel for the whole loop:

```
const timeout = 30 * time.Second
outc := make(chan struct{})
timec := time.After(timeout)

RangeLoop:
for {
    select {
    case <-timec:
        break RangeLoop // timed out
    case out, ok := <-outc:
        if !ok {
            break RangeLoop // Channel closed
        }
        // do something with out
    }
}
```

Comment: that `break` only breaks from the `select`. You need a label or a return to break from the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote that up too quickly. I added a label, but I guess usually this would be inside a func and a return would be much more readable.